# ASP.NET Core 6 app - Blazor component stops working after page refresh on production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am facing weird issue. I've added Blazor Sever to my existing ASP.NET Core app.

I was developing with develop `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and everything seems to work fine.

However when I switched to Production for profiler, first I was using my Razor component in View like

```
<component type="typeof(Modal)" render-mode="Server" />
```

All worked fine after initial project start, but after page refresh component was not rendered at all.

So I switched to

```
<component type="typeof(Modal)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

But now, component renders every time and works only after first page open after debug started.

After page refresh no onclick events are triggered, even after multiple page refresh.

All works fine only after initial page open after debug started.

How can I be sure it will work in production ? As It seems something is wrong if I switch profiler to Production on local environment.

Edit:
Actually realised - that it's not due to changing profiler, it happens on Develop too. Randomly it works sometimes even after 2 refreshes of the page and then all of the sudden component stops responding and I have to restart whole project

I've even made a clean component just to remove any code issues so my Modal component is like

```
@using new_project.Views.Shared.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;

<div> Just a test of component </div>

@code {


}
```

Summary:
No matter what I do if it's `Server` or `ServerPrerendered` blazor components stops working sometimes after first refresh, sometimes after couple other refreshes of the page, and then never comes back unless I restart the project.
There is no errors in chrome console or Output terminal in Debug.

Comment: make sure you have used `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` in _Layout.cshtml file. Program.cs :builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(); and app.MapBlazorHub(); . here is the document you can refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server . if it still does not work could you please share reproducible sample code. check console for any error.

Comment: All this was done, and there is no console errors. And all works fine in Development profiler, but when I switch to Production profiler, it only works at the first start, and after page refresh - component is gone.

Comment: I've added additional comment to the main post. it's not actually due to profiler. it happens on develop too. it's random and I don't understand what is causing component stop responding

Comment: I've  put <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> to the very end of the <head> and it seems to help, but it still happened randomly when I refresh page and component is not rendering

Comment: The issue you are facing is random so it is difficult to find actual cause it would be great if you can share the reproducible sample